# unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class

Tags: python, django

I am pretty new to coding and trying to make a website in django. I have broken something while trying to filter the class UserBets by the currently logged in user. Can anyone see what i have done wrong?

```
# views.py
class UserBetListView(ListView):
    model = UserBets
    template_name = 'betassistant/userbets.html'
    context_object_name = 'my_bets'
    paginate_by = 8

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return UserBets.objects.filter(User=user)

# urls.py
 path('userbets/<str:username>', UserBetListView.as_view(), name='bet-userbet'),

# models.py
class UserBets(models.Model):
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=sport_choices, default='NRL')
    bet_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=bet_choices, default='H2H')
    Tipper_Choices = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=tipper_choices, default='Trypod')
    bet_ammount = models.FloatField(max_length=10, default=2)
    bet_odds = models.FloatField(max_length=10, default=2)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=result_choices, default='Winner')
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sport

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('bet-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: You models is missin the class definition. The problem may lay there. You should also insert the outcome (the error and stacktrace) to the question, not just the title.

Comment: Can you try in django shell to run the UserBets.objects.all()? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your model properly, change

```
sport = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=sport_choices, default='NRL')
bet_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=bet_choices, default='H2H')
Tipper_Choices = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=tipper_choices, default='Trypod')
bet_ammount = models.FloatField(max_length=10, default=2)
bet_odds = models.FloatField(max_length=10, default=2)
result = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=result_choices, default='Winner')
User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.sport

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('bet-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

> to

```
class UserBets(models.Model):
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=sport_choices, default='NRL')
    bet_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=bet_choices, default='H2H')
    Tipper_Choices = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=tipper_choices, default='Trypod')
    bet_ammount = models.FloatField(max_length=10, default=2)
    bet_odds = models.FloatField(max_length=10, default=2)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=result_choices, default='Winner')
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sport

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('bet-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

> Update your get_queryset method in views.py to:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return UserBets.objects.filter(User__username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

Comment: Sorry I must have cut that line out, the model is already labelled like that. The views seems to be the problem return UserBets.objects.filter(User=user)

Comment: Try to update your filter query in the get_queryset() method as well.